# Asterisk sip.conf Configuartion for outbound calls

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm sending outbound calls from asterisk server using sip account. I want to use separate IPs for voice an signaling for these outbound calls. Please guide if any idea regarding this, how should I configure it in sip.conf.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the RTP / media address IP in the `[general]` section of your `sip.conf`:

```
[general]
; media address
media_address=10.10.5.2
; depending on your nat & situation you might need for signalling:
externaddr=10.10.5.1
localnet=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```

Then you can confirm this by running:

```
ast*CLI> sip set debug on
```

And look for the media address in the SDP payload under `c=`.

Word to the wise: make sure you check your routing on your box too, e.g. `route -n` and make sure things are headed where you expect them to.

Comment: Thanks dougBTV for such detail explanation. I hava make configuration and now when i originate a test outbound call.Its not working. Following are the logs:

Comment: From: "Anonymous <sip:anonymous@anonymous.invalid>; tag=as773d6f15 To: <sip:03430500000@10.XXX.XX.XXX>
Contact: <sip:anonymous@10.XXX.XX.XXX:5060>
Call-ID: 5dfba41f0c38c6900a75364b7da11e0c@10.XXX.XX.XXX:5060
CSeq: 102 INVITE User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.32.3
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

Comment: Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 286
v=0 o=root 1627537766 1627537766 IN IP4 10.XXX.XX.YY
s=Asterisk PBX 1.8.32.3
c=IN IP4 10.XXX.XX.YY t=0 0 m=audio 13382 RTP/AVP 3 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000 a=fmtp:101 0-16 a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

Comment: Please update your answer to include your configurations and the results of your call origination, including how you originate the call. Thanks.

Comment: Dear dougBTV,
 I have to configure seaprate IPs for voice and Signalling. 
voice IP is 10.XXX.XX.142 and signalling IP is 10.XXX.XX.150
 I have make configuration in sip.conf like this:
`[general]
context=default 
media_address=10.XXX.XX.142
externaddr=10.XXX.XX.150
nat=force_rport,comedia`

Comment: This is how I am testing outbound call `originate SIP/10.XXX.XX.142/03430XXXXXX application playback vm-goodbye` and `originate SIP/10.XXX.XX.150/03430XXXXXX application playback vm-goodbye` Following are the resulting logs: `== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[Jul 2 14:14:38] WARNING[23561]: chan_sip.c:3821 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 2fb3ad7d558c2d85619519e3651a4ff7@10.XXX.XX.137:5060 for seqno 102 (Critical Request) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/ ... nsmissions
Packet timed out after 32000ms with no response`